# XML: How to parse 2 levels of nested List items?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file that contains info and lyrics about songs, and generate a text file to be consumed by another program. Below is a complete sample XML file that must be parsed.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<song xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song" version="0.8" createdIn="OpenLP 1.9.9" modifiedIn="OpenLP 1.9.9" modifiedDate="2015-12-02T00:52:19">
  <properties>
    <titles>
      <title>_Les Test Song</title>
      <title>alternate title here</title>
    </titles>
    <comments>
      <comment>some comments or notes here</comment>
    </comments>
    <copyright>©some statement here</copyright>
    <verseOrder>i1 v1 c1 b1 p1 e1 o1</verseOrder>
    <ccliNo>123456789</ccliNo>
    <authors>
      <author>Author Unknown</author>
    </authors>
    <songbooks>
      <songbook name="Hymnal" entry="2"/>
    </songbooks>
  </properties>
  <lyrics>
    <verse name="v1">
      <lines>verse one lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="c1">
      <lines>Chorus 1 lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="b1">
      <lines>Bridge 1 lyrics</lines>
      <lines>line 2</lines>
      <lines>line 0</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="p1">
      <lines>Pre-chorus lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="i1">
      <lines>intro lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="e1">
      <lines>Ending lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
    <verse name="o1">
      <lines>Other lyrics</lines>
    </verse>
  </lyrics>
</song>
```

Some things to note about the file contents:

1. The file uses 1 namespace
2. There are 2 main nodes within the primary
   <*song*> node named <*properties*> and <*lyrics*>
3. The first "main" node <*properties*> contains metadata about the
   song
4. The second "main" node <*lyrics*> contains a list of verses and
   their lyrics
5. Within each <*lyrics*> node, there are 1 or more verses
   tagged as <*verse*>
6. Within each <*verse*>, there are 1 or more lines to
   the verse tagged as <*lines*>
7. I need to preserve the relationships of
   lines to verses to each song
8. To restate the basic structure, a song has metadata and 1 or more verses, and a verse has 1 or more lines

My thoughts are to grab the song's metadata (author, title, etc.), then create a List of verses using a foreach loop, and within this loop, create a nested List of lines using another foreach loop.

I am open to using any technique, however, I have spent time trying both XMLDocument class and the XDocument class with Linq.

Here is what I have done so far with the XMLDocument class.
My classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace openlpimport
{
    public class Song
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string copyright { get; set; }
        public string ccli { get; set; }
        public string hymnal { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
        public string playorder { get; set; }
        public List<Verse> verseList { get; set; }

        public Song()
        {
            verseList = new List<Verse>();
        }
    }

    public class Verse
    {
        public string verseName { get; set; }
        public List<Lyric> lyricList { get; set; }

        public Verse()
        {
            lyricList = new List<Lyric>();
        }
    }

    public class Lyric
    {
        public string verseLyric { get; set; }

        public Lyric()
        {
            verseLyric = "N/A";
        }
    }
```

Here is what I have for code:

```
    public class XMLParser
    {
        public static Song ParseByXMLDocument()
        {
            var thisSong = new Song();
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\\Users\Les\Documents\XML2TXT\_Les Test Song (Author Unknown).xml");
            XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song");
            XmlNode SongTitleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:title", nsMgr);
            thisSong.title = SongTitleNode.InnerText;
            XmlNode SongAuthorNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:author", nsMgr);
            thisSong.author = SongAuthorNode.InnerText;
            XmlNode SongCopyrightNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:copyright", nsMgr);
            thisSong.copyright = SongCopyrightNode.InnerText;
            XmlNode SongCCLINode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:ccliNo", nsMgr);
            thisSong.ccli = SongCCLINode.InnerText;
            XmlNode SongHymnalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:songbook", nsMgr);
            thisSong.hymnal = SongHymnalNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("entry").Value;
            XmlNode SongNotesNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:comment", nsMgr);
            thisSong.notes = SongNotesNode.InnerText;
//  Define nodes to loop through Song Verses
            XmlNodeList VerseListNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ns:verse", nsMgr);
            foreach (XmlNode node in VerseListNode)
            {
                var thisVerse = new Verse();
                thisVerse.verseName = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
//  Define nodes to loop through Song Verses
                XmlNodeList LineListNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ns:lines", nsMgr);
                foreach (XmlNode node2 in LineListNode)
                {
                    var thisLyric = new Lyric();
                    thisLyric.verseLyric = node2.InnerText;
                    thisVerse.lyricList.Add(thisLyric);
                }
                thisSong.verseList.Add(thisVerse);
            }
            return thisSong;
        }
    }
```

The 2 PROBLEMS I have run into are this:
1) Using **SelectSingleNode**, the result returns **only the first Course** found in the file as the only Course for each Student.

Sample Result:

_Les Test Song
Author Unknown
@some statement here
123456789
2
some comments or notes here

v1
   verse one lyrics
c1
   verse one lyrics
b1
   verse one lyrics
p1
   verse one lyrics
i1
   verse one lyrics
e1
   verse one lyrics
o1
   verse one lyrics

2) Alternatively, using **SelectNodes**, the result returns **all of the Courses** found in the file **for every Student**.

Sample Result:

_Les Test Song
Author Unknown
@some statement here
123456789
2
some comments or notes here

v1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
c1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
b1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
p1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
i1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
e1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics
o1
   verse one lyrics
   chorus one lyrics
   Bridge one lyrics
   line 2
   line 0rics
   intro one lyrics
   Ending one lyrics
   Other one lyrics

The output that I desire is a plain text file *output.txt* in the following format:

> Title: {Song Title}

Author: {Author or Author Names}

Copyright: {Copyright line, if any}

CCLI: {the CCLI song number (optional)}

Song ID: {(optional)}

Hymnal: {the hymnal page number (optional)}

Notes: {(optional)}

PlayOrder: {(optional) - for more information, see the section below, Configuring the PlayOrder Field.}

(blank line)

Verse 1:

verse 1 line 1
verse 1 line 2
verse 1 line 3
etc.

(blank line)

Chorus 1:

chorus 1 line 1
chorus 1 line 2
chorus 1 line 3
etc.

*ETC., And so forth for all verses and their lines.*

The exact output text file for the input xml file shown at the top of this post would be as follows:

> Title: _Les Test Song
> Author: Author Unknown
> Copyright: ©some statement here
> CCLI: 123456789
> Hymnal: 2
> Notes: some comments or notes here
>
> (blank line)
>
> v1:
> verse 1 lyrics
> (blank line)
> c1:
> Chorus 1 lyrics
> (blank line)
> b1:
> Bridge 1 lyrics
> line 2
> line 0
> (blank line)
> p1:
> Pre-chorus lyrics
> (blank line)
> i1:
> intro lyrics
> (blank line)
> e1:
> Ending lyrics
> (blank line)
> o1:
> Other lyrics

Any guidance in how to get the grouping that mirrors the sample XML song file is most appreciated. Any c-sharp technique will do. Thank you in advance for reading through this rather verbose problem presentation.

Comment: Quick thoughts from your two issues you mentioned. You will have to use SelectNodes. In order to solve the problem of reterieving student specific courses first Select all student nodes. Then iterate over every student node and use studentNode.SelectNodes("//ns:course")

Comment: You might consider using [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387067.aspx) instead of the old [XML DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It's much easier to write queries with the newer API.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq like below.  I moved verseName into the Lyrics class which makes more sense.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace openlpimport
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        const string FILENAME3 = @"c:\temp\test3.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            XElement xmlSong = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = xmlSong.Name.Namespace;


            Song song = new Song()
            {
                title = doc.Descendants(ns + "title").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                author = doc.Descendants(ns + "author").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                copyright = doc.Descendants(ns + "copyright").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                ccli = doc.Descendants(ns + "ccliNo").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                hymnal = doc.Descendants(ns + "songbook").Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                notes = doc.Descendants(ns + "comment").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                verseList = new List<Verse>() { 
                    new Verse() {
                       lyricList =  doc.Descendants(ns + "verse").Select(x => new Lyric() {
                                verseName = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                verseLyric = x.Element(ns + "lines").Value
                       }).ToList()
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Song));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME2);

            //Title: _Les Test Song
            writer.WriteLine("Title: {0}", song.title);
            //Author: Author Unknown
            writer.WriteLine("Author: {0}", song.author);
            //Copyright: ©some statement here
            writer.WriteLine("Copyright: {0}", song.copyright);
            //CCLI: 123456789
            writer.WriteLine("CCLI: {0}", song.ccli);
            //Hymnal: 2
            writer.WriteLine("Hymnal: {0}", song.hymnal);
            //Notes: some comments or notes here
            writer.WriteLine("Notes: {0}", song.notes);
            //(blank line)
            writer.WriteLine();
            //v1:
            foreach (Verse verse in song.verseList)
            {
                foreach (Lyric lyric in verse.lyricList)
                {
                }
            }


            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Song")]
    public class Song
    {
        [XmlElement("Title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Author")]
        public string author { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Copyright")]
        public string copyright { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Ccli")]
        public string ccli { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Hymnal")]
        public string hymnal { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Notes")]
        public string notes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PlayOrder")]
        public string playorder { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Verse")]
        public List<Verse> verseList { get; set; }

        public Song()
        {
            verseList = new List<Verse>();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Verse")]
    public class Verse
    {
        [XmlElement("LyricList")]
        public List<Lyric> lyricList { get; set; }

        public Verse()
        {
            lyricList = new List<Lyric>();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Lyric")]
    public class Lyric
    {
        [XmlElement("VerseName")]
        public string verseName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("VerseLyric")]
        public string verseLyric { get; set; }

        public Lyric()
        {
            verseLyric = "N/A";
        }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've incorporated your suggestions and it runs with no errors. My next step is to simply create an output text file with the results in the following structure:

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've incorporated your suggestions and it runs with no errors. My next step is to simply create an output text file with the results in the following structure: Metadata elements, then each verse followed by each verse's lines. For example:<br/>Author<br/>etc.<br/>v1<br/>verse 1 lyrics<br/>c1<br/>chorus 1 lyrics<br/>etc.<br/><br/>Any idea how to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks you very much @jdweng. I apologize for being unclear. My output needs to be plain text, not xml. The point of this little project is to convert an xml output file that one program generates into a txt file that another program imports. I do not have access to source code of the two programs, just their output and input file formats.

Comment: XML file is a text file that can be read by any program that can read and parse strings from a file. The 3rd file produces the following : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Song>
  <br>_Les Test Song</br>
  <br>Author Unknown</br>
  <br>©some statement here</br>
  <br>123456789</br>
  <br>Hymnal</br>
  <br>some comments or notes here</br>
  <br />
  <br>v1</br>
  <br>verse one lyrics</br>
  <br>c1</br>
  <br>Chorus 1 lyrics</br>
  <br>b1</br>
  <br>Bridge 1 lyrics</br>
  <br>p1</br>
  <br>Pre-chorus lyrics</br>
  <br>i1</br>
  <br>e1</br>
  <br>o1</br>
  <br>Other lyrics</br>
</Song>

Comment: Hi @jdweng. Thanks again. Producing an output file in xml format defeats the purpose because the point of the exercise is to produce a plain text file in the format I included in the post (I revised it to include the output text format. I have two programs not mine: one produces the xml file, the other imports the text file. I am simply trying to write a program that will take the xml output file and convert into the text file format the other program will read.

Comment: Thanks again. Your file test2.xml does not output the multiple verse lyric lines, only the first line for each verse. Your file test3.xml is not useful because it is another XML file and not the final output I desire. Also, it only includes the the first line for each verse.

Comment: What exactly is your final output?  The 3rd file includes all the lines in your example when you run the code.  I didn't post all the lines in my last comment because the entire xml was too long to fit into a comment.

Comment: I have included at the bottom of the post the exact text output for the xml input at the top of the post. Please note the b1 group as it has 3 lines. Any of the 7 groups could have more than one lines as b1 does.  Thanks.

Comment: You were using <br> tags which go me confused.  You need to use a StreamWriter and use the WriteLine() method to output data to the file.

Comment: Change code to get you started.  You need to finish the formating at the end.

Comment: I thought I made changes.  They didn't show up so I edited the posting again.